# DataGridTextColumn Binding to IDictionary

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have an ObservableCollection that holds collection of User

```
class User
{
  public int Id{ get; set; }
  public UserType UserType{ get; set; }
}
```

and an enum

```
enum UserType
{
  Admin,
  Moderator,
  User,
  Guest
}
```

and then I have a mapper for the enum called UserTypeMap that can be accessed from ViewModel

```
public class UserListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ......
  public ObservableCollection<User> Users
  {
    get{ return this.users; }
    set{ this.users = value; this.InvokePropertyChanged( "Users" );
  }
  public IDictionary<UserType, string> UserTypeMap{ get; set; }
  {
    get{ return this.userTypeMap; }
    set{ this.userTypeMap= value; this.InvokePropertyChanged( "UserTypeMap" ); 
  }
  ....
}
```

on client side, I made a DataGrid that holds list of user

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
  <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="ID"/>
  <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{**??????????**}" Header="Type"/>
</sdk>
```

I don't know how to bind **dictionary value** to **DataGridTextColumn**,
I tried to use combobox before, using SelectedValue and ItemsSource and it worked,
but I want to display it on text box / label, not on combobox...

Is there a pure xaml way (not code behind page) to do this?

Thanks,
Will

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but I think to only display the enum you don't need the UserTypeMap Dictionary.

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UserType, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0}}" Header="Type"/>
```

Comment: I don't want to display the key (enum), I want to display the value which is string. for example if I have key Admin and I want to display "Administrator", but thanks anyway